# How do I filter by STAT with ps?

Tags: command-line, ps

I am trying to get all the processes for which the value corresponding to the STAT column is X.

I have done this using awk

`ps -aux | awk {'if ($8 ==  "S") print $8" "$11'}`

However, I would like to do it without using a program other than ps. Is there a way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ps` has limited filtering capabilities, but even Linux's `ps` with its myriad options can't filter by status. So you will need an external filtering tool.

You can simplify the set of options. `-ax` is equivalent to the portable `-e` to display all processes. You can use `-o` instead of counting and selecting columns with awk.

```
ps -e -o stat,command | grep '^S '
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there probably isn't a way. `ps` has a few process selection options, but (at least the one on my system) doesn't have a way to filter on the status. You can check the manual page (`man ps`) on your system to confirm.

Note that it's using things like `awk`, `grep`, etc. to find the bits of output you're interested in is the normal, expected way to use a Linux/Unix shell. If you do that often, and want to save re-typing it, you can use a shell function defined in your `.bashrc` or similar, or put a shell script somewhere in `$PATH` (often, `$HOME/bin`).

For example, a shell function taking one argument (the status to look for):

```bash
ps_for_stat() {
    ps -aux | awk {'if ($8 ==  "'"$1"'") print $8" "$11'}
}
```

You could then run: `ps_for_stat S`

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the extra info on the shell script.

Comment: Got the shell function working after figuring out that I needed to add an additional line after it: "export -f ps_for_stat". Thanks again!